# How do we display a progress bar in C# for a button click event in WebForm?

Tags: c#, progress-bar, webforms, buttonclick

I have a button click event which does a lengthy function and takes time. So i want to display a progress bar. Can you let me know how can I do it.

I am very new to .NEt .. any help appreciated

Thanks in Advance,
Amritha

Comment: WinForm/WPF/Silverlight/WebForm/ASP.NET MVC?

Comment: I Would require something much more basic like using an update progress bar, I dont know the way to use it

Comment: @Amritha, what Danny is asking if it is an ASP.NET app or windows form app (or something else)?

Comment: @Amritha: for anything involving a UI, the way to do it will differ a lot between the various UI frameworks, so without knowing what UI environment you are targeting, it's more or less impossible to answer your question.

Comment: I am using VS 2010 and building an ASP.net Web app. So i am looking for displaying a progress bar on click of a button. Thank you

Answer (score 0):

I think this example is *basic* enough:

```
<form id="form1" runat="server">
   <asp:ScriptManager ID="sm" runat="server" />
   <asp:UpdateProgress runat="server" id="PageUpdateProgress">
         <ProgressTemplate>
             Loading...
         </ProgressTemplate>
   </asp:UpdateProgress>
   <asp:UpdatePanel runat="server" id="Panel">
         <ContentTemplate>
             <asp:Button runat="server" id="upd" onclick="updButton_Click" 
                   text="click to update" />
         </ContentTemplate>
   </asp:UpdatePanel>
</form>
```

In code behind `updButton_Click` takes a long time to update, during the period you will see *Loading...* on the page, you can change the text to a `<img src="blabla" />` to make it more like a `ProgressBar`(such as a GIF moving-bar image)